# Broke My Media Query Some How

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[link]http://ramadaan.rocks/test.html?nocache=1

Somehow I broke my media query. Trying to make a nav and now when under 600px, the  media query seems to not be working.

So where is the media query being broken? Is the nav too long? Too many list items?

Any help? Thanks,

```
.nav ul { 
list-style: none; 
background-color: #000; 
text-align: center; 
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

}

```
.nav li { 
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px; 
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 40px; 
height: 40px; /* line-height and height set at same value centers the content vertically in the middle */
border-bottom: 1px solid #888; 
color: #fff;
```

}

```
.nav a { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #fff; 
display: block;
transition: .3s background-color;
```

}

```
.nav a:hover { 
background-color: #e17143;
```

}

```
.nav a.active { 
background-color: #fff; 
color: #e17143; 
cursor: default;
```

}

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
.nav li { 
    width: 120px; 
    border-bottom: none; 
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
}
```

}

```
.nav li { 
float: left;
```

}

```
.nav ul { 
overflow: auto;
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
.nav { 
background-color: #444;
```

}

```
<div class="nav">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What Is Ramadan?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How Do I Fast?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Who Can Fast?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prophetic Commentary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tarawih Prayer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">30 Ajza' of Qur'an</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Commonly Asked Questions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is your intended result? *" the media query seems to not be working"* - is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to create "breaks", where at 600px, a different set of styles would be applied to the page. I think I may have actually fixed it while in the interim: [link]http://ramadaan.rocks/test.html?nocache=1

Still...I would like the nav to be on one line but I seem to be having trouble doing that.

Comment: As Jack as mentioned, perhaps you should mention your intention. Also, you're possibly running into an issue because .nav li has values that are declared outside of the media query that are also inside it (height, line-height). You can either put the value outside in a media query with (min-width: 600px) or put !important next to your values inside the media query.